# Is there a way to get a 'refreshed' saved entity when saving with JPA in Spring boot?

Tags: java, mysql, spring, spring-boot, jpa

First of all, I am not certain if this is caching requests or otherwise just not populating fields.

I have an entity called `CmsRegions`, which contains the following:

```java
public class CmsRegions extends Model implements Serializable {
       
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Basic(optional = false)
    @Column(name = "id")
    private Integer id;
    
    @Basic(optional = false)
    @NotNull
    @Size(min = 1, max = 100)
    @Column(name = "name")
    private String name;
    
    @Lob
    @Size(max = 65535)
    @Column(name = "description")
    private String description;
    
    @Size(max = 2)
    @Column(name = "lang")
    private String lang;
    
    @Size(max = 2)
    @Column(name = "locale")
    private String locale;
    
    @Basic(optional = false)
    @NotNull
    @Column(name = "is_active")
    private short isActive;
    
    @Column(name = "parent_id")
    private Integer parentId;
        
    @Basic(optional = false)
    @Column(name = "created", insertable = false, updatable = false)
    @Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
    private Date created;
    
    @Basic(optional = false)
    @Column(name = "modified", insertable = false, updatable = false)
    @Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
    private Date modified;


    ...getters and setters etc...
}
```

I have the basic repository call to retrieve the entity as:

```java
@NoRepositoryBean
public interface BaseCmsRepository<T extends Serializable> extends JpaRepository<T, Long> {
    
    @Query("SELECT a FROM #{#entityName} a WHERE a.id = :id")
    List<T> getById(
            @Param("id") Integer id
    );
```

When I save the entity, it saves to the database fine into the following table:

```sql
CREATE TABLE `cms_regions` (
  `id` int unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `name` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `description` text,
  `lang` char(2) DEFAULT NULL,
  `locale` char(2) DEFAULT NULL,
  `is_active` tinyint unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `parent_id` int unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
  `created` datetime DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  `modified` datetime DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=32 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

The `created` and `modified` fields get set fine as expected, but the resulting entity I get from my save action, has `NULL` values for the created and modified dates.

I ran a test - my last insert ID was 31, so I added the following code to my controller:

```
    cmsService.saveRegion(region); // save entity

    CmsRegions  testreg1 = cmsService.getRegion(1);
    CmsRegions  testreg2 = cmsService.getRegion(region.getId());
    CmsRegions  testreg3 = cmsService.getRegion(30);
    CmsRegions  testreg4 = cmsService.getRegion(32);  // currently saved entity new ID (32)
```

When doing this - testreg1 contained the created and modified dates as Date objects as hoped. testreg2 contained null values (region.getId() = 32 at this point). testreg3 contained the Date objects for created and modified.

The final value, testreg4 was also NULL. The kicker is, next time I ran it, testreg4 had the values in it for `created` and `modified`. But the next iteration, (33) in testreg2 was once again NULL.

[image: image of data in debug]

I do not know if this is a caching issue, or what. It just seems that if I try to pull the database value before the call has finished - EVEN though the data is now in the database (confirmed with breakpoints) - the resulting fields are always null. Next run, they are populated.

Why? What do I need to do to get these values?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When saving using `JpaRepository#save` or this method on any similar interface, the entity from the database is returned. You can just use it. It's most commonly used to populate the generated id:

```
assertNull(entity.getId());
entity = entityRepository.save(entity);
assertNotNull(entity.getId());
```

It's a bit more complex when the other process is changing the data and persistence context is not refreshed. Another query would be needed then. You can go around that by using `EntityManager#refresh` and passing the entity you would like to "refetch" from the database. Currently I don't know whether that mechanism is present in spring-data-jpa.

Comment: I did attempt to use em.refresh, but even this approach was doing a full on new query to the database. Why are the historic records working but current one is not?

Comment: @BarryChapman you can used the entity returned when saving, when it is not possible or there are other changes, another query is necessary. Check out my edit.

Comment: I am going to add a custom repo to extend and use the refresh method, give me a few minutes to put it in